# How to save an SVG string to file in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using [this wordcloud generator](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud) to do as the name suggests, and would like to save the contents as `.svg`. The library has a `to_svg()` function, which returns a string. It also has a `to_file()` which doesn't save in this format.

Is there any way to use `pyplot`'s savefig function to save the string output from `to_svg()` to a file?

Comment: Why do you want to use `pyplot.savefig` for this? You could just `with open('my.svg', 'w') as svg: svg.write(the_string)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't use `pyplot.savefig`, but it needs nothing beyond the `wordcloud` library you linked and Python itself:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wc = WordCloud()
wc.generate_from_text('This is a word cloud example which has a few words, showing them word for word in a cloud.')

svg_text = wc.to_svg()
with open('my.svg', 'w') as f:
    f.write(svg_text)
```

The output is the word cloud .svg you're after.

[image: this is a screengrab from the .svg in InkScape]

Comment: Sorry about the mouse cursor in frame :)